# Scrolling the recycleview automatically in android

Tags: android

I have created the recycleview with horizontal scrolling function.I have used the view flipper function but it does not only the the image gets blink for particular interval.Now i want to implement the scrolling function automatically that is if i have opened the page the recycle items(Imageview and text view) get scrolled automatically. `

```
 public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private final Context mcontext;
        private final List<Movie> movieItems;


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public  TextView horz_title,amount;
            public ImageView horz_image;
            public ViewFlipper flip;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                flip = (ViewFlipper)view. findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

                horz_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.horz_title);
                 horz_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.horz_image);
            }
        }

        public HorizontalAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Movie> movieItems) {

            this.mcontext = mcontext;
            this.movieItems = movieItems;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_list, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {



            final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
            URL url = null;
            String image=m.gethorizontal1_image();
            try {
                url = new URL(image);


                Glide.with(mcontext).load(String.valueOf(url)).into( holder.horz_image);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (m.gethorizontal1_title()!=null){
                if (!m.gethorizontal1_title().equals("null")){
                    holder.horz_title.setText(m.gethorizontal1_title());
                }
            }

            holder.flip.startFlipping();
            holder.horz_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Date now = new Date();
                                String arriveformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd EEE").format(now);
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                Date departformat1 = new Date(now.getTime() + 604800000L);
                                departformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd EEE").format(departformat1);
                                selectroom = "1";
                                selectguest = "1";
                                to = "10000";
                                from = "10";
                                Intent search = new Intent(Home.this, Detail_page.class);
                                search.putExtra("hotelid", m.gethorizontal1_hotelid());
                                search.putExtra("city", m.gethorizontal1_city());
                                search.putExtra("arriveformat", arriveformat);
                                search.putExtra("departformat", departformat);

                                search.putExtra("selectguest", selectguest);
                                search.putExtra("selectroom", selectroom);
                                search.putExtra("from", from);
                                search.putExtra("to", to);

                                Log.d("detailresponse", "detailresponse -----" + search.toString());
                                startActivity(search);


                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return movieItems.size();
        }
    }
```

`This is my xml code`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:flipInterval="2000"
            android:gravity="center" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/horz_image"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/nature"


            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/horz_title"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"

            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text=""
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horz_image"
            />
</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("new_hotel");

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //   int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("hotel_id").toString());
                String name = jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString();
                final String image = jsonObject.optString("logo").toString();
                Log.d("response", "response -----" + image);

                Movie movie = new Movie();


                movie.sethorizontal1_title(jsonObject.optString("hotel_name").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_image(jsonObject.optString("logo").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_hotelid(jsonObject.optString("hotel_id").toString());
                movie.sethorizontal1_city(jsonObject.optString("city").toString());
                movieList.add(movie);
                listview1.setAdapter(adapter1);
                //listview1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(Home.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                listview1.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
                final int speedScroll = 150;
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    int count = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(count < movieList.size()){
                            listview1.scrollToPosition(++count);
                            handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
                        }


                    }
                };

                handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like I have done in my project(Tested):

```
 final int speedScroll = 150;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count < list.size()){
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(++count);
                handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
            }


        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
```

Comment: I have use this function but it does not scroll can you post your code briefly where i have to paste the above code

Comment: add above code outside of your for loop.... once your adapter is set with all your data then call above code. It will definitely work.